# How to split/create an array on repeated duplicated key

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

```
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}]
```

Need output like below,
On repeat of key "a", need to create new array till the same key repeat

```
[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4}]
[{a:5},{b:6},{c:7}]
[{a:8},{c:9}]
```

Comment: What's the problem? Loop through the input array. Whenever the key of the object is `a`, start a new output array.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best performance don't mutate the source and don't push by 1 element, rather slice:

```js
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}];

let result = [], prev = 0, i = 0, [sc] = Object.keys(test[0]);
while(++i < test.length) sc in test[i] && result.push(test.slice(prev, prev = i));
result.push(test.slice(prev));

result.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="5000000">
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}];

// @benchmark Roko C. Buljan
[...test].reduceRight((acc, ob, i, ref) => 
  (ob.hasOwnProperty("a") && acc.unshift(ref.splice(i)), acc)
, []);

// @benchmark Siva KV
{
const result = [];
let row = [];
test.forEach((item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  if (key === "a") {
    if (row.length > 0) {
      result.push(row);
    }
    row = [item];
  } else {
    row.push(item);
  }
});
if (row.length > 0) {
  result.push(row);
}
result;
}

// @benchmark Alexander
let result = [], prev = 0, i = 0, [sc] = Object.keys(test[0]);
while(++i < test.length) sc in test[i] && result.push(test.slice(prev, prev = i));
result.push(test.slice(prev));
result;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like below.

```js
const test = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 3 },
  { d: 4 },
  { a: 5 },
  { b: 6 },
  { c: 7 },
  { a: 8 },
  { c: 9 },
];

const splitByRepeat = (arr) => {
  const result = [];
  let row = [];
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    if (key === "a") {
      if (row.length > 0) {
        result.push(row);
      }
      row = [item];
    } else {
      row.push(item);
    }
  });
  if (row.length > 0) {
    result.push(row);
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(splitByRepeat(test));
```

Comment: `a` is hardcoded, could be not good

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the slice position index as `x`, and slice the array from `x` to `i` indexes, pushing those chunks into a `result` Array:

```js
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}];

const result = [], l = test.length - 1;
let x = 0, i = 0;
while (i<=l) (i++ === l || Object.hasOwn(test[i], "a")) && result.push(test.slice(x, x=i));

console.log(result);
```

Remember that [Object.hasOwn()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is intended as a replacement for [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) - and should be used instead of the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) anyways. When using the `in` operator you could even get a 33% benchmark perf boost, but [***faster*** does not means it's ***correct***](https://jsbench.me/a5lm14qe3q/1) - since the `in` operator *will* return *truty* for inherited properties - giving potentially a wrong result.

- [MDN: `Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)
- [MDN: `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

---

Another example (~55% slower in performance) would be going backwards, by using a more functional approach with: [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), [Array.prototype.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}];

const result = [...test].reduceRight((acc, ob, i, ref) => 
  (Object.hasOwn(ob, "a") && acc.unshift(ref.splice(i)), acc)
, []);

console.log(result);
```

the `test` array if first shallow cloned using the Array Spread syntax `[...test]` and later referenced as `ref`. On every reduceRight iteration, if the `ob.hasOwnProperty("a") &&` matches we append to the accumulator Array `acc` the contents of the `ref` clone from index `i` to the end. Splice modifies the `ref` array making it smaller and smaller. So basically what it does is: takes from `ref` chunks of array data and inserts them into `acc` - returning it.

Comment: `a` is hardcoded, could be not good, plus PHP-style property access

Comment: also doesn't allow falsy values

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with `reduce` function.

```
const test = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{a:5},{b:6},{c:7},{a:8},{c:9}];

const output = test.reduce((result, item) => {
    if ('a' in item) {
        result.push([]);
    }
    result[result.length - 1].push(item);
    return result;
}, [[]]).filter(arr => arr.length > 0);
```

Here, `reduce` function is used to iterate through the test array and accumulate elements into subarrays. Whenever an object with the key `"a"` is encountered, a new empty subarray is added to the result. Elements are then pushed into the most recent subarray.

Finally, the resulting subarrays are filtered to remove any empty ones, and the output will contain the desired grouped arrays.

Comment: unnecessary intermediate array